# .NET web project with logic in a separate DLL is unloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have a .NET web application that uses a separate class library for a lot of the non-UI code. In this library is a static class that is used for site-wide config info. It is initialized during the `Application_Start` event.

I am having a problem in that this critical static object seems to be losing its state intermittently - I assume because the DLL is being unloaded for some reason. It might not happen for days, or it might happen a couple times a day. This happens *without* the application being restarted, though, so the result is that all the data that was initialized during `Application_Start` is lost causing all sorts of problems. Recycling the app pool or otherwise restarting the application fixes it.

After I figured out what was happening I changed the code so that the config object in the class library initializes itself with a static constructor, instead of during the application start phase. This introduces some other complexities not worth going into but I can make it work - I just think it's a bad architecture and should not be necessary.

Should I be able to depend on a static object in an external DLL loaded during `Application_Start` keeping its state for the life of the application? Obviously I can't - and I don't quite know why - but I'm wondering if I should be looking for reasons that the DLL is unloading, or simply accepting that it could and never writing code that depends on static objects outside the main application DLL keeping their values.

Here's what Application_Start looks like.

```
Application_Start() {

    // asp.net routing
    ConfigureRoutes();

    // LF is the static config object in an outside dll
    // the LFFactory object implements session & database stuff that's context-specific
    // (e.g. this is initialized with a different implementation when testing).

    LF.Initialize(new SiteEnvironment.Web.LFFactory());

    // add custom view engine...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ... blah blah 

}
```

Comment: Curious. Usually any types loaded, especially static types, should last for as long as the app pool lasts (and worker process) and be re-fired when the application pool refreshes :/

Comment: have you considered the possiblity that the app pool is recyycling? and is there some specific reason that you cannot include a reference in your project to the DLL and reference it that way?

Comment: Recycling the app pool causes the application to restart - actually I can FIX it by recycling the app pool (since this causes it to be reinitialized). So this isn't the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about including a reference - the DLL is referenced from the main app already.

Comment: To test if Application_Start is firing, you could add a log-statement. I doubt that is the case, but there is no harm in collecting more information.

Comment: Never mind that comment. There are lots of other things going on in Application_Start such as routing table config -- it wouldn't work at all if that ever didn't fire on a restart. Removed my edit :)

Comment: @Lloyd that is what I thought, too, yet something is causing them to be unloaded... it is most baffling.

Comment: I'd be interested to see in what manner you're initializing these classes. Can you show us the relevant portion of your Application_Start method?

Comment: Updated with `Application_Start`... not much to see :)

Comment: Got it. So, your Application_Start is calling a bunch of static methods. Those static methods set static values. And the assumption is that those static values will persist. In light of that, I'm not sure my answer below is terribly helpful (written before I saw this), since Application_Start doesn't seem to know what static properties to keep track of. I'll update my answer with a final suggestion that **might** help though ... assuming **my** assumptions are correct!

Comment: Yeah, basically: it calls a bunch of static methods. Everything related to the framework classes (ViewEngines, Routes) seems fine, but the class from my own DLL gets hosed at some point.

Comment: How can you tell that the data is disappearing?

Comment: Valued commenters - upon further analysis my premise is wrong. It's not that a static class is unloading. It's that the application is being restarted and it's not being properly initialized. Part of the class can only be initialized when an active `HttpContext` is available. Therefore it could not be done in AppStart - instead it was done in Session_Start. So, in some circumstances it appears that `Application_Start` can run WITHOUT causing active sessions to be destroyed, e.g. `Session_Start` not guaranteed to run after `Application_Start`. Will revise q.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it addresses your issue but using static classes inside of a web application are particularly difficult. Classes (static or instance based) with static methods are fine but static properties and fields will cause havoc. Your data will be shared across threads within IIS and data will be overwritten in seemingly random order.

If you are attempting to share static data, put that data in your web.config or cache it on the server. If the data is read / write, put that in an instance based object.

Comment: Part of the purpose of this class is to make read-only data easily accessible to the application without having to use untyped, longhand system methods to access the data. I could have it not cache the data from web.config, but that's only part of the problem. It also is used for lots of other reasons e.g. there is a script resolution table that is built on app start by scanning the file system, it would be very inefficient to do this more than once. It's perfectly thread safe - is it really not acceptable to use static data storage in a web application?

Comment: I would avoid static data in a web app... hopefully others will comment as it is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it mainly for configuration data, I would recommend that you put that configuration data into your site's Web.config file. You can(should?) then wrap this in a class similar to what you have now. That class can then consists of some accessors which read the config file and store the results into static memory. If for some reason, the data is lost, then the accessors should not have any problem simply re-loading from the configuration file on the fly.

I hope this is what you are looking for. I am not entirely certain on what type of *configuration data* you are loading and whether or not it can be represented/stored in a XML configuration file.

I would imagine the class to look something like the following:

```
public static class MyConfig
{
  static MyConfig() { LoadConfigData(); }

  public static string ConnectionString
  {
    get
    {
      if (_connectionString == null) { LoadConfigData(); } //assignment of static data done here
        return _connectionString;
    }
  }
  private static string _connectionString = null;

  // repeat for other config-settings...
}
```

Comment: Some of it is just web.config stuff, but there's much more to it than that - it also contains data related to routing, script resolution, and other stuff. It's kept outside the main app because it is needed for testing. The architecture is surely not ideal but I'm not really interested in reworking it at this point - I just want to understand why it won't stay loaded or if it's just not supposed to.

Comment: AFAIK static data should not be unloaded from your application. However, the approach listed above should still work if you wrap your configuration files within accessors. If you're accessor detects a `null` value for a property, it can re-run the `Init()` function (which you can also call in your static constructor) that will load all of your configuration data.

Comment: Changing the class to test every property each time its accessed would be a lot of work - i can accomplish the same thing the way I'm already working around it (using static constructor). I'm really just trying to understand why this is necessary since as you say static data should not be unloaded...

Comment: Yes, it could potentially be a lot of work, but this is simply a _workaround_ for your current problem. However, I'm not sure that I can help you with your current problem of losing static data randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Before having an answer to my question above, or knowing what your static members look like, I'll take a shot in the dark and say that static objects are equally liable to vanish when the reference count hits 0 as is any other object.

A potential solution would be to maintain a "guaranteed" application-persistent reference to the object, even if you don't access the object via that reference:

```
// for each static property we need to keep in memory
Application.Add("MyClass.property", MyClass.property);
```

Retrieve the objects one of two ways:

```
// our object should always be accessible like this
Object a = Application["MyClass.property"];

// and because we've created an application-persistent reference to the property,
// it should also be accessible like this
Object b = MyClass.property;
```

Just a hypothesized, shot-in-the-dark suggestion though!

**ADDENDUM:**
If Application_Start can't feasibly be expected to know each static object it needs to keep track of, I'd suggest iterating over the attributes of your class using reflection, adding each static property as you go.

Comment: Interesting.. certainly worth a shot!

Comment: I definitely look forward to hearing the final solution. It's a very interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.  The problem may be that the Application Pool is recycling.  This will loose the shared memory.  You can adjust when and if the application pool recycles.